# Fitting Flex Image in Canvas

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

How do I scale an Image in Flex to fit a Canvas?  My code follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:VBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
         horizontalAlign="center"
         width="100" height="100"
         verticalGap="0" borderStyle="solid"
         initialize="onLoad()"
         horizontalScrollPolicy="off"
         verticalScrollPolicy="off">
    <mx:Canvas width="100%" height="100%" id="PictureBox" horizontalScrollPolicy="off"
         verticalScrollPolicy="off" />
    <mx:Label id="NameLabel" height="20%" width="100%"/>
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
        private function onLoad():void
        {
            var image:SmoothImage = data.thumbnail;

            image.percentHeight = 100;
            image.percentWidth = 100;
            this.PictureBox.addChild(image);

            var sizeString:String = new String();

            if ((data.fr.size / 1024) >= 512)
                sizeString = "" + int((data.fr.size / 1024 / 1024) * 100)/100 + " MB";
            else
                sizeString = "" + int((data.fr.size / 1024) * 100)/100 + " KB";

            this.NameLabel.text = data.name + " \n" + sizeString;

        }
        ]]>
        </mx:Script>
</mx:VBox>
```

I am trying to get the image:SmoothImage into PictureBox and scaling it down.

**Note** SmoothImage derives from Image.

Comment: What does SmoothImage derive from? Image?

Comment: Yes, it just sets the smooth property.

Comment: Some how scalex and scaley work.  I don't know the math I need now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to make sure you have set

```
image.scaleContent = true;
image.maintainAspectRatio = false;
```

That should scale the content to the size of the swf loader and distortin it so it fills the entire area of the Image component.

Here's a quick version of it working

```
     <mx:VBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
         horizontalAlign="center"
         width="100" height="100"
         verticalGap="0" borderStyle="solid"
         initialize="onLoad()"
         horizontalScrollPolicy="off"
         verticalScrollPolicy="off">
    <mx:Canvas width="100%" height="100%" id="PictureBox" horizontalScrollPolicy="off"
         verticalScrollPolicy="off" />
    <mx:Label id="NameLabel" height="20%" width="100%"/>
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Image;

        private function onLoad():void
        {
            var image : Image = new Image()
            image.source = "http://i.stackoverflow.com/Content/Img/stackoverflow-logo-250.png";
            image.scaleContent = true;
            image.maintainAspectRatio =false;
            image.percentWidth = 100;
            image.percentHeight = 100;

            PictureBox.addChild(image);

        }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:VBox>
```